# how to get selected index for h:selectOneMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I want to get the selected index for my h:selectOneMenu field.

I can either use javascript or jquery

please help

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="myId" value="#{AddScriptBean.scriptEngine}"  >
        <f:selectItems value="#{AddScriptBean.scriptEngines}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your selectOneMenu is rendered as `select`.

With jquery you can use this to get the selected index.

```
 $(function(){
        $('#myId').prop('selectedIndex')
    });
```

With javascript it would be

```
document.getElementById('myId').selectedIndex
```